# react-native-snap-carousel omit sliderWidth and itemWidth and infer from flex?

Tags: ios, react-native, mobile

Looks like the component requires absolute numbers itemWidth and sliderWidth. Is it possible to omit these and just provide flex styles?

Answer (score 0):

Try importing `Dimension` from `react-native` and provide `itemWidth` and `sliderWidth` dynamic value like below -

```
<Carousel
   ...
   sliderWidth={Dimensions.get('window').width}
   itemWidth={Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.8}
   ...
/>
```

Comment: What if I have elements around the carousel? As in: <Icon1/><Carousel /> <Icon2/>

Comment: You can try to give dynamic width to the surrounding components as well, like -
`<Icon1 width={Dimensions.get('window').width *0.15} /> <Carousel sliderWidth={Dimensions.get('window').width*0.7} /> <Icon2 width={Dimensions.get('window').width *0.15} />`